# Assign Several Controls to an Array

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to use Ctype on a few textboxes I have so that I can put them in an array like so

```
    dim textboxes(12) as textbox
    for i=0 to 11
        textboxes(i) = Ctype(form1.controls("textbox" & i+1), textbox)
    next
```

This works fine for most of my controls. It does not work however, for any control that is within a TabControl. I thought that maybe doing something like

```
    Ctype(form1.tabcontrol.control("textbox" & i+1), textbox)
```

might work, but it does not seem to help either.

Additional info: This is a winforms project.

Comment: if you already have the reference, `"textbox" & i+1` just put them in the array: `textboxes(0) = TextBox1` no need to fish them out of the controls array.  Also turn on Option Strict.

Comment: @Plutonix Are you suggesting I write every control out line by line as opposed to doing it in a for loop? ie. 
`textboxes(0) =textbox1 
textboxes(1)=textbox2 
...`
I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: The controls on a TabControl are located on one its tab pages, not on the TabControl itself.  So you'll need code that looks like Form1.TabControl1.TabPages(0).Controls("textbox" & i+1).  This gets rapidly impractical...

Comment: `Dim myTBs As TextBox() = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3...}`

Comment: @Steven why would you load up an array of controls in memory when they already exist on your form?  This is not a good design and definitely not elegant.

Comment: @fernan. Is it preferable to rewrite very similar lines of code repeatedly for various conditions as opposed to looping through an array? Perhaps it takes more memory but it is easier to read IMHO. Or perhaps there is an alternative I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Steven I don't know what you are trying to achieve with your code but the more elegant and reusable alternatives include inheritance and design patterns... if you want different behavior for different conditions the look up the strategy pattern. If you believe that having your textboxes in a collection is a better approach then the form already has a controls collection with your textboxes included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my initial question. As Hans points out in his comment,

> The controls on a TabControl are located on one its tab pages, not on the TabControl itself.

So the correct code is something like:

```
    dim textboxes(12) as textbox
    for i=0 to 11
        textboxes(i) = Ctype(form1.tabcontrol.tabpages(0).controls("textbox" & i+1), textbox)
    next
```

After doing a bit of research and reading the various comments and warnings from other users, I realized that this is not the best way of approaching this problem, and I do not need to initialize an array for my textboxes. It is better not to put them in an array to make it easier to call them, but rather just call them like so

```
for i=0 to 11
    form1.tabcontrol.tabpages(0).controls("textbox" & i+1).text = "sometext"
next
```

Answer (score 0):

TabControls have a collection of TabPage, which have a collection of Control. You'll need to scan all of these. Just scan them all and check if they are indeed checkboxes.

Also, I strongly suggest you use iterators (*For Each* is syntactic sugar for iterators), indexes get messy at some point.

```
dim myBoxes as new List(of TextBox)

For each tab as TabPage in form1.tabcontrol.TabPages
    For each ctrl as Control in tab.Controls
         If ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)
             myBoxes.Add(Ctype(ctrl, TextBox))
         End If
    Next
Next

'If you do need an array
return myBoxes.ToArray()
```